# How to export Event logger events in twincat 3 and write the logged events into a file?

Tags: logging, plc, twincat, st

As of now I have created a few events and used a FB_tcmessage function block to fetch the diplay text of the event and concatenated time stamp in string format and trying to write it into a txt file, but after the write operation the txt file shows the events log in some different language [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV6YD.png)

The OS of the PLC is windows 10

the code to generate events is:

```
IF  NOT bOnce THEN                  // Create event once after power ON. Need to add multiple instances. one for each event.
    bOnce:=TRUE;
    
    FB_TcAlarm.Create   (   
            eventClass      :=  TC_EVENT_CLASSES.NewEventClass,
            nEventId        :=  Event_ID, 
            eSeverity       :=  TcEventSeverity.Info ,
            bWithConfirmation:= FALSE, 
            ipSourceInfo:= 0);  
    
        
    FB_TcMessage.Create(
        eventClass:=TC_EVENT_CLASSES.NewEventClass ,
        nEventId:=Event_ID ,
        eSeverity:= TcEventSeverity.Info,
        ipSourceInfo:= 0);
    
END_IF
FB_TcMessage.RequestEventText(
    nLangId := 1033,
    sResult := sContent,
    nResultSize := 1000,
    bError=>,
    hrErrorCode=>);
    
    
IF  bGenerateEvent THEN             // This is to generate event.
    bGenerateEvent      :=  FALSE;
    FB_TcAlarm.Raise(0);
    FB_TcMessage.Send(0);           // Pass 0 to enter current Time automatically
END_IF
IF  bResetEvent THEN                // Clear generated event.
    bResetEvent     :=  FALSE;
    FB_TcAlarm.Clear(0,FALSE);
    //FB_TcMessage.Release();
END_IF
to write this data into a file the code is:
rtWrite(CLK := bWrite, Q=> );
rtRead(CLK  := bRead , Q=> );
rtDelete(CLK:= DeleteFile , Q=> );
fbFileDelete(
        sNetId:= sAMSNetId, 
        sPathName:= sPath, 
        ePath:= PATH_GENERIC, 
        bExecute:= rtDelete.Q , 
        tTimeout:= DEFAULT_ADS_TIMEOUT, 
        bBusy=> , 
        bError=> , 
        nErrId=> );
    
CASE nState OF
    00: 
        fbFileOpen(bExecute := FALSE);
        fbFileWrite(bExecute:= FALSE);
        fbFileRead(bExecute := FALSE);
        fbFileClose(bExecute:= FALSE);
        
        IF rtWrite.Q AND NOT bReadDone THEN
            nModeFile := FOPEN_MODEWRITE;       //FOPEN_MODEWRITE OR FOPEN_MODEBINARY;
            bFileOpen := TRUE;
            nState    := 10;
            bWriteDone:= TRUE;
        END_IF
        IF rtRead.Q AND NOT bWriteDone THEN
            nModeFile := FOPEN_MODEREAD;        //;FOPEN_MODEREAD OR FOPEN_MODEBINARY;
            bFileOpen := TRUE;  
            nState    := 10;
            bReadDone := TRUE;
        END_IF
    
    10: // open file
            fbFileOpen(
                sNetId      := sAMSNetId, 
                sPathName   := sPath, 
                nMode       := nModeFile, 
                ePath       := PATH_GENERIC,  
                bExecute    := bFileOpen,  
                tTimeout    := DEFAULT_ADS_TIMEOUT, 
                bBusy       =>  ,
                bError      =>  , 
                nErrId      =>  , 
                hFile       => hFile);
                
            IF NOT fbFileOpen.bBusy  THEN
                IF NOT fbFileOpen.bError THEN
                    bFileOpen := FALSE;
                    IF bWriteDone THEN
                        nState    := 20 ;
                    ELSIF bReadDone THEN
                        nState    := 30 ;
                    END_IF
                END_IF
            END_IF
            IF fbFileOpen.bError THEN
                    nErrorState:=nState; 
                    nState:= 99;
            END_IF
            
    20:  // Write into file
            fbFileWrite(
                sNetId      := sAMSNetId, 
                hFile       := hFile, 
                pWriteBuff  := ADR(stWriteRetain), 
                cbWriteLen  := SIZEOF(stWriteRetain), 
                bExecute    := TRUE, 
                tTimeout    := DEFAULT_ADS_TIMEOUT, 
                bBusy       => , 
                bError      => , 
                nErrId      => , 
                cbWrite     => );
                
            IF NOT fbFileWrite.bBusy THEN
                IF NOT fbFilewrite.bError THEN
                    fbFileWrite(bExecute := FALSE);
                    nState    := 40;
                    bWriteDone := FALSE;
                END_IF
            END_IF
            IF fbFileWrite.bError THEN
                    nErrorState:=nState; 
                    nState:= 99;
            END_IF
                            
    30: // read from file
        fbFileRead(
                sNetId      := sAMSNetId, 
                hFile       := hFile, 
                pReadBuff   := ADR(stReadRetain), 
                cbReadLen   := SIZEOF(stReadRetain), 
                bExecute    := TRUE, 
                tTimeout    := DEFAULT_ADS_TIMEOUT, 
                bBusy       => , 
                bError      => , 
                nErrId      => , 
                cbRead      => , 
                bEOF        => );
                
                IF NOT fbFileRead.bBusy THEN
                    IF NOT fbFileRead.bError THEN
                        fbFileRead(bExecute:= FALSE);
                        nState:= 40;
                        bReadDone := FALSE;
                    END_IF
                END_IF
                
                IF fbFileRead.bError THEN
                    nErrorState:= nState;
                    nState     := 99;
                END_IF
    
    40: // file close
            fbFileClose(
                sNetId      := sAMSNetId, 
                hFile       := hFile, 
                bExecute    := TRUE, 
                tTimeout    := DEFAULT_ADS_TIMEOUT, 
                bBusy       => , 
                bError      => , 
                nErrId      => );
                
            IF NOT fbFileClose.bBusy  THEN
                IF NOT fbFileClose.bError THEN
                    fbFileClose(bExecute:= FALSE);
                    nState:= 0;
                END_IF
            END_IF
            
            IF fbFileClose.bError THEN
                nErrorState:=nState;
                nState:= 99;
            END_IF
            
    99: // Error state
            nState:= 0;
                    
END_CASE
```

the output in the notepad is:

```
HƒÄHƒì ƒ@× H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ@× H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
H ÄHƒìHƒ`× H‰$H‹ƒ` HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ`× H‰$H‹ƒH HÿÐf ¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒïÓ HƒìHƒè× H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  Hƒè×  ‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒØ H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$   ƒØ H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ8Ø H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$ EôˆD$ Hƒ8Ø H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒhØ HƒìHƒpØ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$Hƒ Hƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒpØ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒiØ HƒìHƒØ H‰$H‹ƒÈ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒØ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ°Ø H $H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ°Ø H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àf‰ƒ Ø 3ÀˆƒlØ 3ÀˆƒmØ 3ÀˆƒnØ HƒìHƒÐØ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶Eôˆ $    HƒÐØ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒðØ H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD ¶EôˆD$ HƒðØ H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ Ù H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì ¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    Hƒ Ù H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒPÙ H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$ ƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ HƒPÙ H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ€Ù H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐ ¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ€Ù H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ°Ù H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ°Ù H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒoØ Hƒì HƒàÙ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ HƒàÙ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
 ƒÄ3Àˆƒ Ú 3ÀˆƒÚ HƒìHƒÚ H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ HƒÚ  H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ8Ú H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD  Hƒ8Ú H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒhÚ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$ ¶EôˆD$    HƒhÚ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒˆÚ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì ¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒˆÚ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ¨Ú H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$H ÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ¨Ú H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒÈÚ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf ¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒÈÚ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒÚ 3À°È‰ƒÚ ¸   ‰ƒèÚ HƒìHƒðÚ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒðÚ H‰$H‹ƒ¸  HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒÛ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒÛ H $H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒÚ HƒìHƒ0Û H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$ EôˆD$   Hƒ0Û H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒìÚ HƒìHƒPÛ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$Hƒ Hƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒPÛ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒpÛ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf ¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒpÛ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒÛ H‰$H‹ƒÈ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ HƒÛ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒíÚ HƒìH ƒ°Û H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ°Û H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
Hƒ 3ÀˆƒîÚ HƒìHƒÐÛ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒÐÛ H‰$H‹ƒ¸  HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3À‰ƒðÛ 3ÀˆƒïÚ HƒìHƒøÛ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$ ¶EôˆD$  HƒøÛ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒÜ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒÜ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ8Ü H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$Hƒ Hƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ8Ü H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒXÜ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf ¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒXÜ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒxÜ H‰$H‹ƒÈ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒxÜ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ˜Ü H‰ $H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    Hƒ˜Ü H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìH ¸Ü H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ¸Ü H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ HƒìHƒèÜ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒèÜ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒôÛ 3ÀˆƒõÛ 3ÀˆƒöÛ 3Àˆƒ÷Û HƒìHƒÝ H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒÝ H‰$H‹ƒè HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ`Ý H‰$H‹ƒ  HÿÐf¶D$Hƒ Hƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ`Ý H‰$H‹ƒðœ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒÝ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf ¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ HƒÝ H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ°Ý 3Àˆƒ±Ý Hƒì ƒ¸Ý H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$   Hƒ¸Ý H‰$H‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
H Ä¸Ð  ‰ƒ´Ý HƒìHƒØÝ H‰$H‹ƒÈ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒØÝ H‰$ ‹ƒ¸ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ²Ý 3Àˆƒ³Ý 3ÀˆƒøÝ HƒìHƒ Þ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄ ƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$   Hƒ Þ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒùÝ 3ÀˆƒúÝ HƒìHƒÞ H‰ $H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒÞ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒûÝ  3ÀˆƒüÝ HƒìHƒ Þ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ Þ H‰$H‹ƒP  HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒýÝ 3ÀˆƒþÝ 3ÀˆƒÿÝ HƒìHƒ0Þ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì ¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  Hƒ0Þ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ@Þ 3ÀˆƒAÞ HƒìHƒHÞ H‰$H‹ `‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒHÞ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒBÞ 3À ƒCÞ 3ÀˆƒDÞ 3ÀˆƒEÞ 3ÀˆƒFÞ HƒìHƒXÞ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶E ˆD$ HƒXÞ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒGÞ HƒìHƒhÞ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄ ƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ HƒhÞ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒxÞ HƒìHƒ€Þ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ€Þ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒyÞ HƒìH Þ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒÞ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ 3ÀˆƒzÞ HƒìHƒ Þ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    Hƒ Þ H‰$H‹ƒP‘  HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ{Þ 3Àˆƒ|Þ HƒìHƒ°Þ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$ EôˆD$  Hƒ°Þ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ}Þ 3Àˆƒ~Þ 3ÀˆƒÞ 3ÀˆƒÀÞ 3ÀˆƒÁÞ Hƒ HƒÈÞ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒÈÞ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$ HƒÄ3ÀˆƒÂÞ HƒìHƒØÞ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$   HƒØÞ H‰$H ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒÃÞ HƒìHƒèÞ H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶Eôˆ $ HƒèÞ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3ÀˆƒÄÞ 3ÀˆƒÅÞ 3ÀˆƒÆÞ 3ÀˆƒÇÞ HƒìHƒøÞ H‰ H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒøÞ H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒß HƒìHƒß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$   Hƒß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒ ß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    Hƒ ß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ ß 3Àˆƒ
ß 3Àˆƒß 3Àˆƒß 3Àˆƒ
ß HƒìHƒ0ß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf ¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    Hƒ0ß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒß HƒìHƒ@ß  ‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  Hƒ@ß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ ß HƒìHƒPß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ HƒPß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐ ¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ`ß HƒìHƒhß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒhß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒaß 3Àˆƒbß 3Àˆƒcß 3Àˆƒdß HƒìHƒxß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ H Ðf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    Hƒxß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒeß HƒìHƒˆ  H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒˆß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3 ˆƒfß HƒìHƒ˜ß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒ˜ß H‰$H‹ƒP‘  ÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒgß 3Àˆƒ¨ß HƒìHƒ°ß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶E ˆD$  Hƒ°ß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ©ß 3Àˆƒªß HƒìHƒÀß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$  HƒÀß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ«ß HƒìHƒÐß H‰ $H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$    HƒÐß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒ¬ß  3Àˆƒ­ß 3Àˆƒ®ß 3Àˆƒ¯ß 3Àˆƒàß HƒìHƒèß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$ ¶EôˆD$   Hƒèß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒáß HƒìHƒøß H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$ ƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒøß H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄHƒìHƒà H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐ ¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$ Hƒà H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$
HƒÄ3Àˆƒâß 3Àˆƒãß Hƒ Hƒà H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶EôˆD$   Hƒà H‰$H‹ƒP‘ HÿÐf¶D$ HƒÄ3Àˆƒäß 3Àˆƒåß 3Àˆƒæß HƒìHƒ(à H‰$H‹ƒ`‘ HÿÐf¶D$HƒÄHƒì¶EˆD$¶Eô
```

Comment: Please provide some lines of your output file as plain text instead of immage. This way, It is much easier to work with it for everyone who wants to help you. Also, this might help to find weather there is an encoding issue or not. (Here is [why not to post pictures if possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15432738).)

Answer (score 0):

The best method to do this would be to use the _ITcEventLogEvents interface outside of the PLC:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tceventlogger/12332916235.html&id=

The interface provides the callback method to keep a client in sync with the actual state of the TcEvent Logger.

Samples are listed here:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tceventlogger/12332916235.html&id=

Comment: The links provided above say file not found. Can you share any alternate link which would help?

Comment: I updated the links. Google is your best friend for searching BIS